# Which is faster, a directive or one-time binding in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array I want to print on a webpage. The array doesn't change so I don't want Angular watching it's value. W/that in mind, I ask the following question ...

Is it faster to use a directive to grab a scope variable and create an HTML element using this variable as a hard-coded string within the HTMl element

```
[   e.g. el.html('<div>' + $scope.value + '</div>')   ]
```

, or ... use a template that has a one time data binding **w/:: syntax**

```
[   e.g. {{::value}}   ]?
```

Comment: I'd say you are over thinking things and should use the standard expression approach. Your first approach requires a directive that will get watched anyway

Comment: The first approach doesn't create an ng-bind class on the element, so I don't think it gets watched.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to use the angular one time binding as opposed to creating the elements manually. If you are worried about the overhead of a one-time binding, it may be best to use a different framework. A major goal of angular is to minimize direct DOM manipulation.

Comment: Joel, I'm just trying to optimize my code. I'm not worried about anything. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two methods is almost certainly trivial unless you're dealing with a VERY large array. My suggestion would be to go with what is cleaner, and in this case it looks like the one-time data binding is going to be the cleanest implementation (and arguably faster).

Comment: I'm concerned about watchers. The template I want to create has upwards of 10 watchers per item. In an effort to reduce the bindings so that they aren't a part of the digest, I'm looking for ways to remove watchers. What's funny is that even one data binding in Angular adds the class ng-bind.

Comment: In that case I believe the point of one-time data binding is to minimize watchers. The value will only be watched until it is stable, which would be after the first digest cycle in your case.